# Oculus Lip sync IOS support

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, oculus

I have made an app which is using audio lip sync and it runs fine on android, and mac but when I build it for iOS it is keep giving me this error:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OVRLipSync': The specified
>   module could not be found.   at OVRLipSync.ovrLipSyncDll_Initialize
>   (Int32 samplerate, Int32 buffersize) [0x00000] in :0
>   at OVRLipSync.Initialize (Int32 sampleRate, Int32 bufferSize)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at OVRLipSync.Awake () [0x00000]
>   in :0    (Filename: currently not available on
>   il2cpp Line: -1)

Is this a known issue?? or any new bug in the latest package??

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out Oculus Lip Sync **doesn't support iOS** yet and they don't plan to do it in the near future.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: And here is where this is documented as far as I could find it: https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/62624/oculus-lip-sync-not-working-with-ios